# Qt - Displaying results of PowerShell run through QProcess

Tags: c++, windows, qt, powershell

I am working on a project in Qt (v4.7) which requires me to run commands through Windows PowerShell in a QProcess. This is what I have so far (with a sample command):

```
QString path = "C:/Windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe";
QStringList commands;
commands.append("-Command");
commands.append("invoke-command -computername mycomputer -credential myuser {ipconfig /all}");
QProcess *p = new QProcess();
process->start(path, commands);
```

This all seems to work and run successfully without crashing. Now, I need to be able to display the results of running this PowerShell command. I know when I run it in the cmd window it returns a lot of data, but I haven't really used QProcess at all before this, and I'm having trouble figuring out a way to show the results of the process. If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I'm having trouble..." what have you tried?

Comment: @Merlin069 I haven't really been able to try much, I'm just not sure where to begin with it. I have a slot in the class this is in that is connected to the finished() signal of the QProcess, since I figure anything to get the results would have to wait to run until the process is finished, and that's triggered as expected, but I can't find any way once it's finished to get the result. I've been going through the doc pages but can't find anything to get the results of the QProcess.

Comment: What about connecting a slot to the readyReadStandardOutput signal and calling readAllStandardOutput? It's clearly documented: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your code...

```
QString path = "C:/Windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe";
QStringList commands;
commands.append("-Command");
commands.append("invoke-command -computername mycomputer -credential myuser {ipconfig /all}");
QProcess *p = new QProcess();
```

Assuming you have a slot called readyToRead() in a class MyClass, which has a pointer to the QProcess, p

```
connect(p, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, myClass, &MyClass::readyToRead);
process->start(path, commands);
```

Then you'll receive notification in the slot

```
void MyClass::readyToRead()
{
    QString output(p->readAllStandardOutput());

    //Do something with the string
}
```

Comment: I've found a small problem with this: do you happen to know what I need to change to print the result of the PowerShell when that result is an error message? It turns out I need to return that as well, but right now it just doesn't return anything. I have more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118530/qt-how-to-output-windows-powershell-error-message-via-qprocess

Comment: Does the signal readyReadStandardError not work for you, as defined in the Qt docs here? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardError