# Qt - How to output Windows PowerShell error message via QProcess

Tags: c++, windows, qt, powershell

I am working in Qt 4.7, and I have a program that needs to use a QProcess to output the result of running a Windows PowerShell command. For the purposes of this question, let's say all that needs to be supported is use of the "-Command" option. Right now I have this:

`QString path = "C:/windows/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe";
QStringList command;
command.append("-Command");
command.append(/*Whatever test command I want to use...*/);
process = new QProcess();    //Note: QProcess *process is a member of this class
connect(process, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), this, SLOT(/*slot to print qprocess errors...*/);
connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(/*slot to display PowerShell output...*/);
process->start(path, command);`

The slot to print the PowerShell output is simply as follows:

`std::cout << "RESULT: " << QString(process->readAllStandardOutput()).toStdString() << std::endl;`

This works perfectly with correct PowerShell commands. For example, I tested it with the command "Get-ChildItem C:\", and it printed the correct data. It also works fine if there is a QProcess error. What I need to know how to do is, how can I have it print a *PowerShell* error message? For example, if I try to use the command "Get-ChildIte" (missing the *m* at the end) directly in PowerShell I get an error message. But with my code, it just doesn't print anything. I need it to print that error message. If anyone knows of a way this could be done, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, about a minute after I posted this I discovered QProcess's signal `readyReadStandardError()`, which operates identically to `readyReadStandardOutput` except that it is emitted when whatever the QProcess is running has an error. I connected this to a slot identical to what I have above but instead printing `QString(process->readAllStandardError()).toStdString()` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you posted your answer 7 seconds ago. I just wanted to confirm, and give a link to reference for you that may help troubleshoot this in the future.

[QProcess Class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html)

Yes, you want the readAllStandardError() function of QProcess.

Comment: @LaszloPapp It wasn't a link only answer, the answer was that he needed to use the readAllStandardError function. The link was for future reference in case he needed it. Considering the code that he had already posted, I'm sure he's capable of integrating that function, so I didn't feel the need to include any code. The answer was perfectly functional even without the link.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Thank you for your constructive criticism, I will endeavor to keep things to comments where appropriate in the future, and try not to be overly personable.